# can't boot api 19 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I installed a fresh api 19 emulator (x86 variant) and it doesn't get past the splash screen. someone told me that sometimes it gets finicky that way and I should delete the device and create a new one, so I tried doing that but it goes back to the same problem, infinite "android" splash screen.

how do you diagnose stuff like this? I have several other, newer emulators and they all work.

I have the device frame off just to make sure it is not that.

It is using the 5x as the basis for the device.

I increase the heap size to 256mb, and the ram to 2gb, but otherwise don't change much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up posting a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207255). The bug has been confirmed, given medium priority, and a work-around solution has been outlined which I can confirm works.

Comment: doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.04, unfortunately... :(

Comment: you're probably on a different version of Android Studio by now. :)

Comment: yeah, most probably :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the graphics mode from Hardware/Auto to Software:

1. Go into the AVD Manager, select the Virtual device, and click "Edit"
2. Find "Emulated Performance" -> Graphics, and switch that from auto (or hardware) to Software.

It will not perform well compared to in Hardware mode, but it may give you insight into what is causing the problem if it runs this way. Hopefully Google/Jetbrains will get that figured out in a future update.

Comment: I believe that I tried that but gave up on waiting for it to boot .. perhaps too early. But I don't have this problem with a different API so that doesnt seem like an answer.

I've reported this as a bug now: I have reports from others that they have the same problem with a fresh install of android studio 2.0

Comment: Ahh, yes. If it works for other android images for different APIs, then you're right, this won't be the solution. I know you said API 19, but for some reason I didn't realize you meant *strictly* API 19. Good luck!